# ora-12560 :TNS: protocol adapter error after installing ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle Database 11.2.0.1 Win64 and also Client 11.2.0.1 Win64 in my windows 7 Ultimate and I was able to access Oracle database using Sql*plus 
using `sqlplus / as sysdba`. After that I installed ODP.NET `ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit` to work with Oracle using C# in Visual Studio 2010. When i tried to add connection to Oracle database using ODP it pops out `ora-12560 :TNS: protocol adapter error` and even during logging to Oracle using `SqlPlus / as sysdba`.

I have read several articles that say stopped service will cause but mine is running.

What could be the problem???

Comment: Do I need to install ODP.NET in my laptop if I already had installed Oracle Database Server?

Comment: Check your system path. Make sure the oracle server bin is before the client.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I faced Connecting to Oracle 11g using Server explorer in VS 2010 was not version compatibility of ODP with Oracle database but it's architecture. After such errors  I uninstalled Oracle Database 11g using **deinstall.bat** file then cleaned Registry Key ../Software/Oracle and cleaned up temp files, did a system restart. Then installed Oracle 11g Database x32 Database server, ODP.NET x32, checked Env vars. 
First success was that I was able to connect to DB using `SQL*Plus`. After that started VS 2010  and tried to connect ..... Connected! wow  has worked in VS IDE. I was so happy :)

I remember how many times I reinstalled Oracle(cleaning,configuring checking listeners, restarting services). Then my hard work really paid off.

here is a screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I advise to install Oracle server under different credentials than what you usually use. The Oracle server (under Windows) makes use of a few environment variables; and the same is the case with ODP.NET as well. And while you can't easily switch between different sets of env variables in your user profile, you can assign different env var values to a (different) user under which the Oracle server is installed and/or being run.

If you already have your Oracle server installed (which, I suspect, is your case), then try:

1. Create a new user in your Windows, make him sufficiently privileged. ("Admin" rights will do fine. :-))
2. Log in as the new user.
3. Set up `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID`, `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `PATH` environment variables for that particular user (not globally for the whole Windows!) to point to your Oracle server.
4. Log in as the original user.
5. Start the Services management console ("services.msc").
6. Change "Log On" credentials for the `OracleServiceSOMETHING` and `Oracle SOMETHING VSS Writer Service` and `OracleJobSchedulerSOMETHING` and `OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener` to that new user+password you just created. (... where `SOMETHING` is usually the name of your instance)
7. Stop all Oracle services.
8. Set up `ORACLE_HOME` and `PATH` env var to point to your ODP.NET root and root\bin folders respectively; set up the `ORACLE_SID` and `NLS_LANGUAGE` vars to whatever values you need.
9. Start all Oracle services. (After this moment they should be running under their own credentials.)
10. Let's pray that it works.

I myself would have to improvise, too, if this scenario didn't work. But so far I have successfully run two Oracle servers and one Oracle client on the same machine this way with no problems, so I hope it works for you too. If it does not, then there's still the option of reinstalling your Oracle server completely.

Don't forget about backing up your database ... just in case something horrible happens.